# Can not get string value from controller

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am new in Spring MVC. I want to get a string value from my Controller class to my jsp page.I have goggled it but whic I have try , couldn't get data.Here is my codes,

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/index")
public class MainPageController {

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String buttonText(ModelMap modelMap) {
      if (Constants.loginStatus == false) {
          modelMap.addAttribute("buttonText", "Giriş");
      } else {
          modelMap.addAttribute("buttonText", "Çıkış");
      }
      return "index";
   }
 }
```

headerTemplate.jsp

```
 <div align="right">
    <button type="button"
        style="color: #fff; background-color: #5bc0de; border-color:       #46b8da; box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid transparent; margin-top: 10px; margin-right: 25px; border-radius: 6px;"
        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">${buttonText}      </button>
```

my dispatcher-servlet ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.mesutemre">     </context:component-scan>
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

   <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

and here is my web.xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>BlogProject</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>dispatcher</display-name>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-  class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

how can I get the string value that in my controller to my jsp page.Is there any error code in my xml's.

Comment: So what happens? Is your controller code actually executed?

Comment: It is not to fall breakpoint.So I can't control the controller class.

Comment: You need to hit /index and not index.jsp. Change welcome to /index or point your browser to ..../index i.e. no .jsp extension

Comment: When I remove jsp index , resource not found error getting

Comment: <url-pattern></url-pattern> should be  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

Comment: Update your question to reflect the changes you have made and show the exact URL you are hitting in the browser. Also determine if the Controller executes. If no this issue is with the path you have mapped to the JSP in the controller.

Comment: Also indicate where the JSP files are in your directory tree. e.g. ${webapp-root}/index.jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First things

You can put your index.jsp file in WebContent level not inside WEBINF folder in your project hierarchy.

- Second things

In your request uri write **/index** and hit enter your can redirect index.jsp page as your spring context xml file.

- Testing purpose
  Print out your message in jsp file.